# UserControl with command-property

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I have a `UserControl` for a `LinkLabel` with an Image before.

The XAML looks like:

```
<UserControl>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static helper:ImageHelper.JumpLabelImage}}" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock >
            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding JumpCommand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                       CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The DataContext of this `UserControl` is set to the CodeBehind-File.

The Code-Behind-File looks like:

```
public partial class JumpLabel : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(JumpLabel));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty JumpCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("JumpCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(JumpLabel));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(JumpLabel));

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand JumpCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(JumpCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(JumpCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public JumpLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now I want to call the JumpCommand if the user clicks on the `LinkLabel`

Therefor I use the following code to assign the Command in the view of my MainWindow:

`<view:JumpLabel LabelText="Extensions" JumpCommand="{Binding JumpLabelCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=control}"/>`

In the ViewModel of my MainWindow I have:

```
private ICommand _jumpLabelCommand;
public ICommand JumpLabelCommand
{
    get { return _jumpLabelCommand; }
    set
    {
        _jumpLabelCommand = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    _mainWindowModel = new MainWindowModel();
    JumpLabelCommand = new RelayCommand(DummyExecute);
}

private void DummyExecute(object parameter)
{

}
```

In the DummyExecute I have a Breakpoint which is never reached. I'm not getting it why my Command doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update:**

I've created a new small project with focus on the binding-problem for the Command-Property in the `UserControl`.

The MainWindowView is:

```
<Window x:Class="UCWithDP.View.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:UCWithDP.ViewModel"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:UCWithDP.View"
        Title="MainWindowView" Height="300" Width="600">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding SomeText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <view:JumpLabel Grid.Row="1" JumpLabelText="My Jump Label" JumpCommand="{Binding DoJumpCommand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Some Button" Command="{Binding DoJumpCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The MainWindowViewModel is:

```
 internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _someText;
    private ICommand doJumpCommand;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SomeText = "Hello from ViewModel";
        DoJumpCommand = new RelayCommand(DoJumpExecute);
    }

    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return _someText; }
        set
        {
            _someText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand DoJumpCommand
    {
        get { return doJumpCommand; }
        set
        {
            doJumpCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void DoJumpExecute(object parameter)
    {

    }
}
```

My `UserControl` is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UCWithDP.View.JumpLabel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Height="20"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             x:Name="uc">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="X" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=JumpCommand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding JumpLabelText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code-behind of the `UserControl` is

```
public partial class JumpLabel : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty JumpLabelTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "JumpLabelText", typeof (string), typeof (JumpLabel), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty JumpCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "JumpCommand", typeof (ICommand), typeof (JumpLabel), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public JumpLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ICommand JumpCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(JumpCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(JumpCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public string JumpLabelText
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(JumpLabelTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(JumpLabelTextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In the MainWindowView the Command-Property of my `UserControl` and a `Button` are binded to the same `ICommand`. If I click the `Button` my Breakpoint in DoJumpExecute is reached. If I click on the `HyperLink` the Breakpoint is not reached.

I still don't understand it...

---

**Solution**

In my MainWindowView now I use the following code

```
  <view:JumpLabel Grid.Row="1" JumpLabelText="My Jump Label" 
                        JumpCommand="{Binding DataContext.DoJumpCommand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

and now it works.

Comment: You said that _DataContext of this UserControl is set to the CodeBehind-File_. Can you show how?

Comment: What is the command parameter being passed in. Have you tried the same operation without any command parameter? In your output window in visual studio when debugging do you see any binding expression errors?

Comment: I removed the `DependencyProperty` for the CommandParameter. It still won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the code that you have provided, you could have any number of problems... assuming that you actually have all of the properties that you are using correctly defined, these are the most likely causes of error:

Firstly, when data binding from a `UserControl` XAML page to its properties, you should get used to using the `RelativeSource Binding`, despite its verbosity. Note that you should do this *instead* of setting the `UserControl.DataContext` to its code behind:

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding JumpCommand, Mode=TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourUserControl}}, 
    Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={
        x:Type YourPrefix:YourUserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Hyperlink>
```

Next, you have this line of code:

```
<view:JumpLabel LabelText="Extensions" JumpCommand="{Binding JumpLabelCommand, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=
    control}" />
```

This will of course not work if any of the following conditions are true:

1. You don't have an `ICommand` property named `JumpLabelCommand` in your bound view model, or code behind.
2. You don't have a UI control named `control` in your view.
3. The `DataContext` of the UI control named `control` does not have a suitable value to use as the `CommandParameter` property... perhaps this `Binding` should have been: `CommandParameter="{Binding Propertyname, ElementName=control}"`?

If none of the above conditions are true and you are still having problems, then please edit your question and provide *all of the relevant code*, which should include *everything* that is relevant, eg. details of the `control` element, it's set `DataContext`, etc.

Comment: The RelativeSource in the MainWindowView solved the problem. I added the solution to the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

this is more a general answer: if you create a usercontrol with dependency properties then your binding should always contain some kind of "relative binding" - i always use elementname binding. so your usercontrol binding should look like this.

```
<UserControl x:Name="uc">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static helper:ImageHelper.JumpLabelImage}}" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock >
        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=JumpCommand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=CommandParameter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=LabelText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

if you set the datacontext for your usercontrol to self, then you break the datacontext inheriting and that is not what you want. so you have to remove all kinds of setting the datacontext to self within your usercontrol.

the updatesource trigger are used to handle the update to the source, thats why your updatesource trigger makes no sense in your usercontrol. eg a textblock cant updatethe Text property to source - it would work with a textbox :)

Answer (score -1):

your constructor of JumpLabel Control should be

```
 public JumpLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext=new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
```

Comment: it will break bindings on `JumpLabel` in the `MainWindow` as it will overwrite inherited `DataContext`

Comment: @dkozl: ohh yes it will break the jumpLabel binding I have to delete it